# Adicionar valor ao meu contato para cada múltiplos de 200 sem ter que criar variáveis individuais

Tags: javascript, html, algoritmo

Estou criando um conversor numérico. porém devido ao meu conhecimento
limitado, não consigo programá-lo para que cada vez que alcance um múltiplo de 200 no contador, seja adicionado 4 no resultado.

Eu até consegui um resultado criando uma variável individual para cada múltiplo, porém acredito que não seja a forma mais adequada.

E também meu contador está computando valores negativos.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Conversor</title>
<body>

<h2>Conversor</h2>
<p>Conversor:</p>

<p>
  <label>valor</label>
  <input id="inputValor" type="number" placeholder="valor" oninput="Conversor(this.value)" onchange="Conversor(this.value)">
</p>
<p>Resultado: <span id="outputValor"></span></p>

<script>
function Conversor(valNum) {

  var kwh = valNum; 
  var gre;
  if (kwh >= 200) {
    gre= 4;
  } else {
    gre= 2;
  }  
  var b2 = valNum;
 
  var add; 
  if (b2 >= 200) {
    add = 4;
   } else {
    add = 0;
  
   }
   
     var add2; 
  if (b2 >= 400) {
    add2 = 4;
   } else {
    add2 = 0;
  
   }
   
   document.getElementById("outputValor").innerHTML=valNum*gre+add+add2;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Qual o erro que aparece?

Comment: Bom dia Ronaldo. 
Está rodando, só que gostaria de saber se tem algum método melhor 
do que esse que eu fiz, porque dessa maneira terei que fazer uma variável para cada múltiplo de 200.
para adicionar 4 ao resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem variáveis demais aí. Poderia usar o operador condicional no lugar do `if`. Eu poderia simplificar um pouco mais, mas no fundo ficaria pior, então deixei assim. Também organizei melhor o código.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Conversor</title>
<body>

<h2>Conversor</h2>
<p>Conversor:</p>

<p>
  <label>valor</label>
  <input id = "inputValor" type = "number" placeholder = "valor" oninput = "Conversor(this.value)" onchange = "Conversor(this.value)">
</p>
<p>Resultado: <span id = "outputValor"></span></p>

<script>
function Conversor(valNum) {
    var gre = valNum >= 200 ? 4 : 2;
    var add = valNum >= 200 ? 4 : 0;
    var add2 = valNum >= 400 ? 4 : 0;
    document.getElementById("outputValor").innerHTML = valNum * gre + add + add2;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/FormulaConditional.js).

O AP agora diz que quer outra coisa, quem sabe seja isto que ele quer (note que não faz a mesma coisa):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Conversor</title>
<body>

<h2>Conversor</h2>
<p>Conversor:</p>

<p>
  <label>valor</label>
  <input id = "inputValor" type = "number" placeholder = "valor" oninput = "Conversor(this.value)" onchange = "Conversor(this.value)">
</p>
<p>Resultado: <span id = "outputValor"></span></p>

<script>
function Conversor(valNum) {
    valNum = parseInt(valNum); //não estou tratando se vai dar erro igual ao que foi feito antes
    document.getElementById("outputValor").innerHTML = (valNum * ((Math.trunc(valNum / 200) + 1) * 2)) + valNum + (Math.trunc(valNum / 200) * 4);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/FormulaSteps.js).

Comment: Bom dia eu agradeço atenção, mas a minha duvida é se teria como só fazer uma única var add, e a mesma reconhecer os múltiplos de 200 e adicionar +4 ou vou ter  manualmente fazer var add para cada múltiplo (exemplo: var add3 = valNum >= 600 ? 4 : 0;)

Comment: Mas seu código não faz isso. Você coloca um código, diz que ele está funcionando e só quer melhorá-lo. Eu fiz a melhoria baseado no seu código. Se ele está errado e não faz o que deseja, não deveria dizer o que disse. A resposta que você recebe é de acordo com a sua pergunta. Se deseja outra coisa e não diz não tem como as pessoas adivinharem. Agora você está dizendo que quer outra coisa completamente diferente do que está no seu código. Quem garante que depois de eu fazer desse jeito não acontecerá de ser outra coisa que você não tinha percebido?

Comment: Não foi por mal talvez tenha feito a pergunta de forma errônea, agradeço a paciência e espero que o tópico venha ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: Eu sei que não foi por mal.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tem um exemplo de como fazer isso:

```js
<script>
function Conversor(valNum) {

  var kwh = valNum; 
  var gre;
  if (kwh % 200 == 0) {
    gre= 4;
  } else {
    gre= 2;
  }  
  var b2 = valNum;
 
  var add; 
  if (b2 % 200 == 0) {
    add = 4;
   } else {
    add = 0;
  
   }
   
  var add2; 
  if (b2 % 200 == 0) {
    add2 = 4;
   } else {
    add2 = 0;
  
   }
   console.log(gre);
   var resultado=valNum*gre+add+add2;
   //document.getElementById("outputValor").innerHTML=resultado;
   console.log(resultado);
}
Conversor(1600);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Me corrija se eu tiver entendido errado, mas tente isso:

```js
function Conversor(valNum){
    var gre = valNum >= 200 ? 4 : 2;
    var soma = parseInt(valNum / 200)
    return soma * 4 + valNum * gre;
}
```

Comment: Não funcionou, é que a Var "gre" é para alterar o multiplicador do conversor. ele começa *2 e ao chegar aos 200 ele fica *4, essa parte ta ok.

O problema é que eu quero adicionar +4 a cada múltiplo de 200 (adicionado no input).
sem correlação com var gre.

Comment: Editei o código, veja se é isso por favor.